# Unity rendering issue. There is blue reflection in the terrain which is hiding the objects like grass from far distance

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

[image]

[image]

The blue reflection and normal base of the terrain is shown in the image. How do I make it disappear?

Adding a terrain but could not get the output due to this reflection problem.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour], [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [ask].

Comment: What is your elevation?  You may be looking through clouds.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.